# The Spin version of ${\rm LX}/{\rm SO}(3,1)$ - is it $\widetilde{LX}/ {\rm Spin}(3,1)$?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, spin-geometry

Let X be an orientable smooth manifold and let LX be its frame bundle. It is well-known that the global section of the quotient bundle between the frame bundle LX (with structure group GL$^+$(4)) and the SO(3,1) group are tetrad fields. The tetrad fields uniquely determine a metric. The connections are the metric connections.

I am interested in the spin version of this concept.

In a previous question I was told that I cannot take LX/Spin(3,1) because Spin is not in GL$^+$. Ok, fine.

However, some reading lead me across a concept known as a double cover of GL$^+$(4) (noted $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}(4)$) leading to a double cover of the frame bundle $\widetilde{LX}$.

Can one then take $\widetilde{LX}/Spin(3,1)$ and obtain a tetrad field, where the connection is a spin connection?

I am also interested in learning a bit more about $\widetilde{LX}$ and how can I define its elements canonically. I known that GL$^+$(4) can be represented as the exponentials of matrices. I also know that Spin relates to the exponentials of bivectors in Clifford algebra. From this, can I intuit that the expression of $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}(4)$ are the exponentials of the multivectors of the Clifford algebra?

Comment: Not a differential geometer, but shouldn't we have $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}/{\rm Spin}\cong{\rm GL}^+/{\rm SO}$? I don't think your intuition about exponentials of multivectors representing $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}$ is correct because the dimensions are mismatched.

Comment: @runway44 Yeah, essentially I am asking if this is true $\widetilde{GL^+}/{\rm Spin} \cong GL^+ /SO $? I suspect both $FX/SO$ and $\widetilde{FX}/Spin$ produce a tetrad field. Except one has a spin connection, and the other has a metric connection. How is $\widetilde{GL^+}$ defined?

Comment: @runway44 The exponential of multivectors in 4D contains 16 parameters. How many parameters are in $\widetilde{GL^+(4,\mathbb{R})}$ - I thought it was also 16?

Comment: For $n=4$ there is a coincidence $2^n=n^2$, but not for general $n$. I didn't see anything in the question that specified $n=4$. Even when $n=4$, I think $C\ell(4)\cong M_2(\Bbb H)\not\cong M_4(\Bbb R)$, but I could be wrong. You defined $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}$ to be the double cover of ${\rm GL}^+$. One abstract construction in topology does the path group modulo endpoint-preserving homotopy and loops. You can construct ${\rm Spin}$ as a double cover of ${\rm SO}$ using Clifford algebras, or ${\rm Spin}^c$ as a double cover of ${\rm SO}\times S^1$, but dunno about $\widetilde{{\rm GL}^+}$.

Comment: @runway44 if you exponentiate a multivector of CL(4), you exponentiate a 4x4 matrix. Therefore it is isomorphic to GL+(4), but it includes Spin(3,1) which is a double cover of SO(3,1). This is because multivectors exponentials have an adjoint action $v'=gvg^{-1}$, and this is a double cover because $v'=(-g)v(-g)^{-1}$. Is it then both true and a coincidence of 4D (and possibly 2D) that the exponential of multivectors is the double cover of GL+(4)?

Comment: I suspect you're talking about (3+1)D, or (1+3)D depending on your sign conventions, not 4D. That way you can represent multivectors with $4\times4$ gamma / Dirac matrices, and exponentiating does give you ${\rm GL}_4^+\Bbb R$ (or at least generates it, technically). That is specific to (3+1)D.

Comment: @runway44 Awesome - 3+1D is even better than 4D! Do you think it is true then that in 3+1D, the exponential of multivectors maps to the double cover of GL+(4)?

Comment: @runway44 I am trying to define the pseudo Riemannian metric via a structure reduction $\exp \mathbf{u}$ (where $\mathbf{u}$ is an arbitrary multivector of CL(3,1)) to Spin(3,1) or Spin$^c$(3,1). I apologies if my question lack technical accuracy. Can you help with with this? I have $\exp \mathbf{u}$ and I need the quotient bundle $\exp \mathbf{u} / Spin(3,1)$. Can I do that - does it give a tetrad field?

Comment: Dunno, can't help with that.

Comment: @runway44 How can $\exp u$ maps to $GL_4^+\mathbb{R}$ if Spin(3,1) is in $\exp u$ but not in $GL_4^+\mathbb{R}$? Or is there a low dimensional coincidence that makes Spin(3,1) be in $GL_4^+\mathbb{R}$? Let me also point out that the Dirac matrices are complex-valued and therefore do not exactly map out to the $GL_4^+\mathbb{R}$ group.